# Is there a Command or feature to open ue4 to a specific file in the editor?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I want to build commands, or shortcuts, or hyperlinks that takes a windows user to a specific file (i.e blueprint editor, or any destination file within a ue4 project ) .

Currently i navigate the content browser and double-click files to open them in the editor. I want to deeplink some of these destinations so that I dont have to use the content browser. I prefer an answer that uses executable commands to open files within UE4 (fresh startup, and within existing ue4.exe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The editor has this functionality built into it. It's called *Open Asset...*.

Go to *Main Menu > File > Open Asset...* or press <kbd>Control+P</kbd> or <kbd>Alt+Shift+O</kbd> to bring up the *Open Assets...* window.

[image: Open Assets Window]

You can change the default shortcut keys in *Main Menu > Edit > Editor Preferences... > General > Keyboard Shortcuts > System-wide > Open Asset...*.

[image: Open Asset Editor Command]

### From C++

Use `FContentBrowserModule::SyncBrowserToAssets`.

Example:

```cpp
FContentBrowserModule& ContentBrowserModule = FModuleManager::Get().LoadModuleChecked<FContentBrowserModule>("ContentBrowser");
ContentBrowserModule.Get().SyncBrowserToAssets( InObjectsToSync, false, bFocusContentBrowser );
```

For convenience, you can also use `UEditorEngine::SyncBrowserToObjects` like this:

```cpp
GEditor->SyncBrowserToObjects(Objects);
```

### From Blueprints

Use the *Editor Scripting Utilities* plugin to *Sync Browser to Objects*.

[image: Sync Browser to Objects]

To use this, you must enable the *Editor Scripting Utilities* plugin (currently experimental, API subject to change).

[image: Enable Editor Scripting Utilities Plugin]

Comment: I have the plugin enabled, but still can't call the "SyncBrowserToObjects" in blueprint

Comment: @NobodySomewhere You can't call it or you can't find it? If you can't find it, it may be that you have the *Context Sensitive* checkbox checked. Uncheck it and look again.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out; to be able to call it in a blueprint, the blueprint needs to extend from EditorUtilityObject or EditorUtilityWidget